# how to use gdb to catch "exit" of a program

Tags: gdb

I am debugging a rather complex project, I have its source code, currently I need to know the stack trace when daemon exits in certain case, but it is very time consuming to go through the whole code, I want to use gdb to help on this, but commands like "catch exit" won't work, it told me that "Catch of exit not yet implemented", so can anyone tell me how to use gdb to catch the exit event of a daemon? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think just setting breakpoints for `exit`, `_exit`, and `abort` should get you pretty far.

Answer (score 29):

```
(gdb) catch syscall 60
Catchpoint 3 (syscall 'exit' [60])
(gdb) catch syscall 231
Catchpoint 4 (syscall 'exit_group' [231])
```

Comment: Where do those numbers, 60 and 231, come from?

Comment: @Silicomancer They are syscall numbers. Here's an article listing them: https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/ You can also get documentation for a particular syscall like this: `man 2 exit` , `man 2 exit_group`

Comment: you can also do `catch syscall exit` no need to know the number